# The order in which to perform the transformation $y=f^{-1}(x+2)$ on the original point (10,8). Inverse first?

Tags: inverse

I'm having difficulty understanding this transformation.

What is the correct order of these transformations? How do I find this correctly.

I understand that $y=f^{-1}(x)$ can refer to switching the coordinates (the inverse) (appears as a reflection in the line $y=x$)

I also understand that replacing $x$ with $x+2$ results in points that appear two units left of their original locations.

I am not sure if I can first take the input $x$ and move the point two units to the left to obtain $(8,8)$  which would follow $y=f(x+2)$ then take the inverse of that point.  So the point would be $(8,8)$ which doesn't seem correct.

It seems the correct way is the take the inverse first, $y=f^{-1}(x)$
So reflect in the line $y=x$ to obtain the point $(8,10)$
then use the input (x+2) which results in the point $(6,10)$  Can someone please walk me through this?

The answer says it should be $(6,10)$
It seems that we take the inverse first then replace $x$ with $x+2$ Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To un-nest this composition of functions...

$f(10) = 8\\
f^{-1}(8) = 10\\
f^{-1}(6+2) = 10$

$(6,10)$ is the corresponding point.

or more abstractly

$y = f^{-1}(x+2)\\
f(y) = x+2\\
x = f(y) - 2$